# Configuration for "SeleniumHQ htmlSuite Run" in Jenkins to run Selenium HTML TestSuite

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, functional-testing, test-suite

I want to run my Selenium HTML Test Suite through Jenkins (a continuous integration). The following shows, how the build is configured for the current project:

[image: This is my current Jenkins configuration for the concerned project]

And here's the **console output** after commiting a new test for example:

```
ERROR: The suiteFile is not a file or an url ! Check your build configuration.
Build step 'SeleniumHQ htmlSuite Run' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'SeleniumHQ htmlSuite Run' marked build as failure 
Publishing Selenium report...
Finished: FAILURE
```

In fact, I get these log issues even after committing both extensionless test files AND .html files.

Comment: Have you tried naming a single .html suite file? If you have multiple suites, presumably you can either add multiple SeleniumHQ build steps to your job, or combine all suites into a single .html file.

Answer (score 1):

SeleniumHQ Jenkins plugin supports only ONE suite file per build step. Try out [Selunit](http://www.selunit.org) to run Selenese suites in batch and across multiple browsers. This [tutorial](http://www.selunit.org/2011/05/23/comprehensive-selenium-integration-in-hudson/) shows hot to setup the test execution in Jenkins/Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

Your suiteFile is written with wildcard as: tests/selenium/*.html. I think it is wrong.
You need to provide the exact/absolute path to your suite without the wildcard as below:

tests/selenium/suite.html

Comment: Yes, it needs to write the absolute path of HTML Suite file